# Xamarin Forms save image from an url into device's gallery

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin Forms (with iOS and Android). What I want to do is to allow users to download image from an url by using DependencyService. I tried run in IOS emulator and the image did save into the emulator but does not show up in the gallery.
Appreciate help in that and following is my code:

In ViewModel:

```cs
public void DownloadImage()
{
    IFileService fileSvc = DependencyService.Get<IFileService>();

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(ImgUrl);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    fileSvc.SavePicture(DateTime.Now.ToString(), stream, "temp");
}
```

In Xamarin.iOS

```cs
public void SavePicture(string name, Stream data, string location = "temp")
{
    var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string imageFilename = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Images", location);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(imageFilename);

    string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

    byte[] bArray = new byte[data.Length];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        using (data)
        {
            data.Read(bArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
        }
        int length = bArray.Length;
        fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
    }
}
```

In Xamarin.Droid

```cs
public void SavePicture(string name, Stream data, string location = "temp")
{
    var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    documentsPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Images", location);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsPath);

    string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

    byte[] bArray = new byte[data.Length];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        using (data)
        {
            data.Read(bArray, 0, (int)data.Length);
        }
        int length = bArray.Length;
        fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Want to save image into Gallery, please follow the code below.

Firstly, create Create the IMediaService Interface in PCL.

```cs
public interface IMediaService
{
    void SaveImageFromByte(byte[] imageByte,string filename);
}
```

Then implement this interface in Platform-specific
Xamarin.Android Project

```cs
public  class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    Context CurrentContext => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
    public void SaveImageFromByte(byte[] imageByte, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), filename);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageByte);
            var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path)));
            CurrentContext.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

implement this interface in Platform-specific
Xamarin.iOS Project

```cs
public class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    public void SaveImageFromByte(byte[] imageByte,string fileName)
    {
        var imageData = new UIImage(NSData.FromArray(imageByte));
        imageData.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
        {
            //you can retrieve the saved UI Image as well if needed using  
            //var i = image as UIImage;  
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For accessing the CurrentContext  Install the NuGet Package (**Plugin.CurrentActivity**) from NuGet Package Manager,  also check for the **external storage permission**.

Comment: Hey Cherry, thanks for your reply. When I tried run on ios emulator, the app force quit without generating any error once the debugger touches 

`        imageData.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
`

Do you have any idea on what the issue could be?

Comment: @LongHaoLi on iOS when you want to write photos to album, we need to add Privacy in info.plist. On iOS 11 add NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription, iOS 10 add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription.There are some article about [iOS Security and Privacy Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=macos) and [New iOS 10 Privacy Permission Settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/)

Comment: Hey @CherryBu, thank you so so much for the help! It worked after I added NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription into info.plist!